# vim save recorded macro and apply via script non-interactively

Tags: vim

Is it possible to save a recorded vim macro and apply that macro via a script non-interactively?

For example, suppose I had 100 similar files that looked like this:

```
variable number of lines
foo(a)
some more stuff
variable number of lines
bar(e)
```

In vim, I could record and playback a macro to change those files to something like this:

```
variable number of lines
foo(a, b)
    some more stuff
    variable number of lines
bar(e)
```

The macro would be ugly to read, and could be something like this:

```
ESCqa/foo
/)
i, bESCj0
V/bar
k>ESCq
```

Is there a way to save that macro and apply it non-interactively, e.g. so it could easily be applied to 100 files without interactively opening each file in vim?

---

This is what I've already tried:

Saving my macro as `a`, then writing `apply_a.ex` script:

```
norm @a
w
```

And finally `ex target.txt < apply_a.ex`

This doesn't change the file contents -- it appears the macro `a` is not recognized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `:help starting`

```
-w {scriptout}  All the characters that you type are recorded in the file
        "scriptout", until you exit Vim.  This is useful if you want
        to create a script file to be used with "vim -s" or
        ":source!".  When the "scriptout" file already exists, new
        characters are appended.  See also |complex-repeat|.
        {scriptout} cannot start with a digit.
        {not in Vi}

-s {scriptin}   The script file "scriptin" is read.  The characters in the
        file are interpreted as if you had typed them.  The same can
        be done with the command ":source! {scriptin}".  If the end
        of the file is reached before the editor exits, further
        characters are read from the keyboard.  Only works when not
        started in Ex mode, see |-s-ex|.  See also |complex-repeat|.
        {not in Vi}
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: Is the expectation that nobody actually reads the saved scripts and manually edits them?  They contain unprintable ascii characters so modifying them looks like a pain.

Answer (score 1):

'Sorry for not formatting properly, I am on android'
Have you ever used 'bufdo' or heard of it?
You could open all your files at once and record in your macro something like :bn which goes to next. Bufer and at the end :wall which means write all and finally :qall

Here one example:

Or you can do something like:

vim *
let @a='define your macro including :wn'
normal n @a
:qall

Where * represents all files you need
:wn   means 'write current buffer and go next
n @a  is n times macro a
:qall  means quite all buffers[image]